# Find the area enclosed between the curves $x^2+y^2=4, y=\sqrt 3 x, x >0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Find the area enclosed between the curves $x^2+y^2=4, y=\sqrt 3 x, x >0$.
The first curve is a circle, while the second one is a line. I think that this area equals $\int_0^1(\sqrt{4-x^2}-x\sqrt 3)dx$. Am I right?
EDIT: The area from above is the area above the line $y=x\sqrt 3$, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Do you mean the region *above* the line $y=\sqrt3x$? Or the region *below*?

Comment: Hint: to which angle correspond $y=\sqrt{3}x$ ? Then use that the area of an angular sector is $\frac 12r^2\Delta\theta$ (i.e. integrate in polar coordinates...).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The book doesn't mention. I forgot to add that I computed the area above that line.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just an area of the sector: $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{5\pi}{6}\cdot2^2=\frac{5\pi}{3}.$$
Also, it can be $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{6}\cdot2^2=\frac{\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: Thank you ! The former is for the region below the line, while the latter is for the one above it, right?

Comment: @ChemistryGeek Yes, of course!

Answer (score 1):

The line $y=\sqrt 3\,x$ is the line with slope $\frac\pi 3$ though the origin, so, as I understand it, the area enclosed between the curves is simply  the   sector of the circle with radius $2$ between the polar angles $\frac \pi 3$ and $\frac \pi 2$, so it is
$$\frac12\,4\Bigl(\frac\pi2-\frac\pi 3\Bigr)=\frac{\pi}3.$$

Comment: Thank you !  Anyway, the result is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, you made a miscalculation.

Comment: You're right. I messed up because I had forgotten to type the factor $\frac12$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your integral $\int_0^1(\sqrt{4-x^2}-x\sqrt 3)dx$ is correct, which yields the result $\frac\pi3$.

It'd be easier to integrate in polar coordinates, though. Note that the circle and the line intersect at $r= 2$ and $\theta = \frac\pi3$. Thus, the area integral is,

$$A = \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_0^2 rdr d\theta=\frac\pi3$$